# Get file name of file used to open the associated application

Tags: delphi

I want to write a small app that does some data manipulation on the contents of a simple text file.

I just want to be able to right click such a file, choose 'Open with' in Windows, select my app, then the app opens, parses the file, does some stuff and closes immediately again.

Question: when my app starts, how do I get the file name that triggered the app to start?

Thanks!

Comment: @kobik - That would be the answer.

Comment: Oh great! I knew it must have been somthing simple like that, but when I tried Googling it, I really couldn't find this...

Thanks!

Comment: @Son - Don't forget to test for ParamCount.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, I wonder *who* deleted my comment and why?

Comment: @kobik - Interesting. I wonder why who deleted your comment did not delete mine..

Comment: @kobik I think a moderator deletes it as it was an answer and not a comment. BUT he should have warn you to move it as an answer instead of just delete it without warning.

Comment: @Triden - I believe someone should have flagged it for a moderator to notice it.

Comment: @kobik I up-voted some of your latest (great) answers so I give you (indirectly) the credit for this one ;)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Unfortunately, I do not have enough admin-right to see who deletes the comment. So I cannot know more about this issue.

Answer (score 6):

You get the file as parameter number 1.
You can get it with the function `ParamStr(1)`.

Have a look here for more details:
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ParamStr

For your information, `ParamStr(0)` is the filename (including complete path) of your EXE application.

Comment: I'm curious. Why link to delphibasics rather than the actual documentation? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr

Comment: And `ParamStr(0)` is the same thing as `Application.ExeName`, btw.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Very bad experience with Delphi documentation (you know, since Delphi7 blablabla ...) so I'm still using so (old) bookmark :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because DelphiBasics is awesome and Embarcadero documentation is total crap. They should just take the good, old Delphi7 documentation and publish on the website.